# JavaFx 13 - TableView Vertical ScrollBar handler returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I need to handle JavaFx13 scroll to bottom event, but this code:

```
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     // ...
     // ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) this.emailsTable.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
        ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) this.emailsTable.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        verticalBar.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> { // <-- Line 49
             // if (verticalBar.getOrientation() != Orientation.VERTICAL) return;
            if (newValue.doubleValue() >= verticalBar.getMax()) {
                System.out.println("BOTTOM!");
            }
        });
     // ...
   }
```

...returns that error at FXML load:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at it.unito.prog.views.MainView.initialize(MainView.java:49)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
... 19 more
```

Comment: The commented code also produces the same exception (...slightly different)

Comment: Your `verticalBar` object is null bc `this.emailsTable.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");` returns `null`

Comment: Not everything is initialized by the time initialize is called. Try accessing the property after the scene has actually been shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can scroll using [`tableView.scrollTo()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo(int))  to scroll to either an index or a specific item.

To be notified that a scroll has occurred, you can use [`tableView.setOnScrollTo()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setOnScrollTo(javafx.event.EventHandler)).

*Don't use a lookup for this task*

The scroll bar is only shown as needed. It may or may not be there when you look it up.

If you try to [`lookup()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)) the scroll bar before you add items to the table view, or before you add the table view to a scene, or before the scene has undergone a rendering pass, a scroll bar is almost certain to not be there. If the scroll bar is not there when you try to look it up then the lookup method will return a null value (which is what you are seeing).  Even if a scroll bar is there when you first look it up, it may be subsequently removed and a new one added as needed, so your original reference will end up becoming invalid. So I don't recommend your lookup based approach.

Comment: Generally, good advice to not rely in anything retrieved by lookup be the same later on. But actually, in core implementation of VirtualFlow the scrollBars are created once at instantiation time. Obviously, nothing to rely on :) The reason it's null in the OP's context, is that the table's skin is not installed because the table is not yet added to the scenegraph (in initialize)